# Long list/array into a dictionary with indices as key

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to solve a coding exercise.
Part of it is creating a dictionary from a random list of integers.
The dictionary must have as `key` the index of the element in the original list and as `value` the element of the list.

This is my function:

```
def my_funct(pricesLst):
    price_dict = {}
    for i in range(0, len(pricesLst)):
        price_dict[i] = pricesLst[i]

    print(price_dict)


a = np.random.randint(1,100,5)

my_funct(a)
```

The output I get is the **right** one:

```
{0: 42, 1: 23, 2: 38, 3: 27, 4: 61}
```

**HOWEVER** if the list is longer, I get a weird results as output.

Example:

```
a = np.random.randint(1,1000000000,5000000)
my_funct(a)
```

The output is:

```
{2960342: 133712726, 2960343: 58347003, 2960344: 340350742, 949475: 944928187.........4999982: 417669027, 4999983: 650062265, 4999984: 656764316, 4999985: 32618345, 4999986: 213384749, 4999987: 383964739, 4999988: 229138815, 4999989: 203341047, 4999990: 54928779, 4999991: 139476448, 4999992: 244547714, 4999993: 790982769, 4999994: 298507070, 4999995: 715927973, 4999996: 365280953, 4999997: 543382916, 4999998: 532161768, 4999999: 598932697}
```

I am not sure why does it occur.
Why aren't the keys of my dictionary starting from 0 as it happens for the shortest list?

The only thing I can think of is that the list is too long and thus python, instead of using the index starting from 0 as key, it associate the space in memory.

Comment: it's random integers up to `1000000000` based on your random function, your output is as expected, also depends which python you are using, dicts insertion order is not guaranteed before python36 and is not a language feature until python37

Comment: But shouldn't my price_dict have the keys starting `from 0 up to len( pricesLst)`? Meaning the output will be something like:
`{0: some_number, 1: some_number, ..... 4999999:some_number}`

Comment: please note my comment about dictionaries and insertion order, if you want to have an ordered dictionary prior to python37 you will need to use `OrderedDict`

Comment: Thanks, I understand and I changed it using OrderedDict(), however, the first key still does not start from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because dicts in python are not necessarily ordered. You should use an ordered dictionary which is declared as:

```
my_ordered_dict=OrderedDict()
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionaries are ordered in python 3.7. If you are older python version (<3.7), then you will have to use ordered dictionary.

You can use ordered dictionary as follows:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
def my_funct(pricesLst):
    price_dict = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(0, len(pricesLst)):
        price_dict[i] = pricesLst[i]
    print(price_dict)

a = np.random.randint(1,10000,10000)

my_funct(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get you. I changed my code, but still if `a = np.random.randint(1,10000000000,1000000)`, the first keys do not start from 0

Comment: @FBSO sorted `!=` insertion ordered

Comment: @FBSO, looking at your output, it seems like you are only seeing the last n entries. You are asking the system to print a million rows, so not sure if what you see as the output is the first few and last few items. It is possible the first few entries are somewhere in the middle. I would check using a  simple statement like: print([x for x in price_dict.items()][0:10]) to see what the actual first few keys and values are in the OrderedDict